# can Perl Moose objects have directly an array/hash attribute?

Tags: arrays, perl, attributes, moose

Can be done something like this in Perl?

```
package Person;
use Moose;

has 'friends' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Array', default => () );
```

I see that perl compiler doesn't accept this particular syntax, but do I use wrong syntax, or it is not possible at all? Do I have to use an array reference instead?

I'm pretty new to perl so the question is maybe dumb and I somehow feel the answer would be "no", but I haven't found any mention about it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seeing as you couldn't pass an array to an accessor, can't receive one from an accessor, or store an array a hash (or whatever else Moose objects might be), I don't even know what you even consider an "array attribute". Could you explain what you mean by an "array attribute"?

Comment: `default => ()` makes no sense. It's just a weird way of writing `'default'`.

Comment: Thanks, it basically means for me that it cannot be done. I'm still quite used to PHP where arrays are treated just like normal variables, so I didn't know that an array cannot be passed to an accessor etc.

Comment: Basically means *what* can't be done? Arrays are normal variables in Perl. Arrays can't be passed to accessors because arrays can't be passed to subs because subs can only take a list of scalars for arguments.

Comment: @amik: what you want to do can be done, but you aren't describing what you want to do.  show some code that demonstrates how you want use this attribute

Comment: simply: how can I create a list of friends as an attribute of Person? (I'm really learning basics of Perl OOP, I have no more code...)

Comment: It's odd you mention PHP since it looks like one always deal with arrays through a reference in PHP.

Comment: "list" has quite a few definitions. Presuming you mean an collection or ordered collection of Person objects, I'd use an array I'd pass to the accessor using a reference

Answer (score 7):

"List" has quite a few definitions. Presuming you mean an collection or ordered collection of Person objects, I'd use an array I'd pass to the accessor using a reference

```
has friends => (
   is      => 'rw',
   isa     => 'ArrayRef[Person]',
   default => sub { [] },
);

push @{ $o->friends }, $person;

for (@{ $o->friends }) {
   ...
}
```

You can add useful methods using [Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Array](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Array).

```
has friends => (
   traits  => [qw( Array )],
   is      => 'rw',
   isa     => 'ArrayRef[Person]',
   default => sub { [] },
   handles => {
      push_friends => 'push',
   },
);

$o->push_friends($person);

for (@{ $o->friends }) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not quite what you're asking, but look at array traits - http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute/Native/Trait/Array.pm. Since all of an instance's values are stored in a hashref, you can not store anything other than scalar values, meaning you need to use references. This handles all of the boilerplate you need to work with the internal arrayref.

```
package Person;
use Moose;

has 'friends' => ( is => 'ro', 
                   traits  => ['Array'],
                   isa => 'ArrayRef[Str]',
                   default => sub { [] },
                   handles => {
                                 all_friends    => 'elements',
                                 add_friend     => 'push',
                                 map_friends    => 'map',
                                 filter_friends => 'grep',
                                 find_friend    => 'first',
                                 get_friend     => 'get',
                                 join_friends   => 'join',
                                 count_friends  => 'count',
                                 has_friends    => 'count',
                                 has_no_friends => 'is_empty',
                                 sorted_friends => 'sort',
                             },

                 );
```

Comment: +1 I think array trait is the answer OP sought, along with needing to provide a coderef for default

Answer (score 0):

As a simple answer that at least makes the get/set easier, you can write your own accessor functions to wrap an array ref into an array.  For example:

```
package Person;
use Moo;

has 'friendsRef' => ( is => 'rw', default => sub { []; } );

## A 'set/get' wrapper for friendsRef
sub Person::friends {
  my ($self, @list) = @_;
  return @{$self->friendsRef} unless $#list>=0;
  return $self->friendsRef(\@list);
}

## Example bonus function for adding to list
sub Person::addFriends {
  my ($self, @list) = @_;
  return push(@{$self->friendsRef}, @list);
}
```

Example code usage could be:

```
my $p = Person->new();

$p->friends('Dave','Jerry');
print "Friends are: ",join(', ',$p->friends()),"\n";

$p->friends('Bob','Dave');
print "Friends are: ",join(', ',$p->friends()),"\n";

$p->addFriends('Joe','Cletus');
print "Friends are: ",join(', ',$p->friends()),"\n";

## Note that "$p->friends()" is not a scalar, it's a sub returning an array,
## so instead of "$#{$p->friends()}" you'd want "scalar($p->friends())"
print "Number of friends is ",scalar($p->friends()),"\n";
```

Output is:

```
Friends are: Dave, Jerry          
Friends are: Bob, Dave            
Friends are: Bob, Dave, Joe, Cletus                                 
Number of friends is 4
```